# PHP Swatch download, only generating 2 colours?

Tags: php, html, css, gd, gdlib

I've been working on saving swatches out as images using PHP, I made a head start on it and so far it's saving out the first colour, and last colour and black - but iterating the last colour for three blocks.

```
<?php

$colours = $_GET['c'];
$swatches = explode("|", $colours);


// Create image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 30);


foreach ($swatches as $key => $rgb_set) 
{
if ($rgb_set=="") break;
list($r, $g, $b) = explode(",", $rgb_set);

$x_pos = (24 * $key);

$swatch = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
imagefilledrectangle($im, $x_pos, 0, 24, 30, $swatch);
}


// Set the content type header
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Save the image
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Has anybody any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to resolve this so that it downloads all 5 swatches from a palette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to happen *(at least in part)* due to the hard-coded `24` value in your [`imagefilledrectangle`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) function call.

Instead of this *(note the `24`)*:

`imagefilledrectangle($im, $x_pos, 0, 24, 30, $swatch);`

This:

`imagefilledrectangle($im, $x_pos, 0, $x_pos+24, 30, $swatch);`

So that the `$x2` value of the `imagefilledrectangle` continues to move along with the `$x1` value that you have in your original code.

### Full Code Example

```
<?php
$colours = $_GET['c'];
$swatches = explode("|", $colours);

// Create image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 30);

foreach ($swatches as $key => $rgb_set)
{
    if ($rgb_set == "") break;
    list($r, $g, $b) = explode(",", $rgb_set);

    $x_pos = (24 * $key);

    $swatch = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, $x_pos, 0, $x_pos+24, 30, $swatch);
}

// Set the content type header
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Save the image
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Note:
This has been tested with the following URL query string:
`?c=255,255,0|255,155,25|13,103,100|54,123,53|255,0,0`

Comment: @thesarahjay Glad to hear it; hope the rest of your project goes well!